# How do I write a parameter of a function if its a string in a statement?

Tags: python, function, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a python function with some parameters that are strings in the statement.

```
def deleteElement(file, selector, value):
  with open(file) as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
    removeThis = soup.find('div', {selector : value}) ...
```

When I run the function, do I just type the values with quotes?

```
deleteElement('file.txt', 'class', 'main-div')
```

so that it would be interpreted as:

```
removeThis = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'main-div'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is exactly how you do it.

```
def function (var1, var2, var3):
    print (var1, var2, var3)

function("one", "two", "three")

output: 

>> one two three
```

From the above mentioned example of a simple function you can see that the function variables are just that, normal variables, as such should be defined as any other variable.

Comment: what if I want output:  "one" "two" "three" with quotes?

Comment: You double quote them, but you have to use different quotation marks. Let's say you want your string to contain double quotes  "one" "two" "three", you have to quote each string with single quotation marks  `function('"one"', '"two"', '"three"')`. If you want your strings to contain single quotation marks you do the inverse `function("'one'", "'two'", "'three'")`.

Comment: Thank you! duh :P